# How to create two object drivers of type WebDriver and use the same Classes and Methods

Tags: java, class, selenium, methods

I have a question related to improving my Selenium Java code. I am really beginner in Java and Selenium either.

I have written a code which I got an example from the internet and adapted to my reality. The coding works fine as described below:

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;


import page.Login;

public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

    Login login = new Login(driver);

    @Test
    public void loginWithSuccess() {
        sendLoginData("my_user@something.com", "my_password");
        login.clickLogin();
        assertEquals("View Posted Jobs", login.checkLoginSuccess());
    }

    private void sendLoginData(String user, String password) {
        login.sendUser(user);
        login.sendPassword(password);
    }
}
```

The above program is testing and performing a loginWithSucess in the WebSite

```
package config;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebDriverFactory {

    public static WebDriver createFirefoxDriver() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }   
}
```

In this above example I am instancing a new object WebDriver called driver.

```
package test;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;


import config.WebDriverFactory;

public class BaseTest {
    protected static WebDriver driver;
    private static boolean setUpIsDone = false;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        if (setUpIsDone) {
            return;
        }
//      Creating first browser for student login        
        driver = WebDriverFactory.createFirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://test-tuitiondesk.rhcloud.com/auth");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        setUpIsDone = true;

    }
```

The above example is where I open my WebSite to authenticate

```
package page;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Login {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public Login(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;

    }


    public void sendUser(String user) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys(user);
    }

    public void sendPassword(String password) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickLogin() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-box']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/button")).click();
    }

    public String checkLoginSuccess() {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'View Posted Jobs')]")).getText();
    }

}
```

The above example I have methods which will send a user id and password to the webpage.

So far is everything working fine. The program is performing the following steps:

1 - Open the firefox

2 - Open the webpage

3 - Send the correct user_id, password and click in login button

4 - Check if login was performed with success.

My question now is that I need open a new firefox driver and login with different user_id and this new user_id will interact some actions with the first user_id, so I will need two browsers opened to perform actions with both users in the same time.

I would like to write this implementation the best way than simply write every method again with the second driver. What I thought for the first time was create a new WebDriver called driver2 and create again all methods referring to driver2, but I think I should reuse my methods and classes in a clever way.

Does Anybody have any idea how to implement this second browser in my code?

Thank you

André

Comment: So, what if you modify sendLoginData() to accept an instance of Login and return the browser, then what happens if your LoginTest creates a second instance of Login to pass to that sendLoginData() method?  i don't know if this would work...I haven't ever tried to work with multiple browsers at once.

Comment: It worked the way you suggested. Now sendLoginData() has one more parameter of type Login and then I pass as parameter my first driver or my second driver created (instantiated) before. Thanks @BreaksSoftware

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by entering this code:

```
    driver2 = WebDriverFactory.createFirefoxDriver();
    driver2.get("http://test-tuitiondesk.rhcloud.com/auth");
    //call log in function for driver2
    //code to interact driver2 with driver1
```